# Fitness app for Apple Watch that automatically ends the "Outdoor Walk"/"Dog walk" workout when I return home

Tags: geo-location, fitness

When I am out on a "Outdoor Walk" or "Dog Walk" workout being recorded in a fitness app, I frequently forget to end the recording upon returning to the house.

Both the Apple fitness app and the [Gentler Streak](https://www.gentler.app/) app will eventually prompt me to end the recording, I wish this were done automatically.

Given that the app knows I am outside walking, and given that the app knows my current location, and also given that the app knows where I live (and where I started), well, why can't the app deduce that I have returned home and automatically end the recording?

Is there any such app available for Apple Watch?